# What is wrong with my code here? I am getting the right output for test cases, I tested for different self made test cases, it passes those also

Tags: c

I was tring to solve this question, "You are given an integer N. Consider the sequence containing the integers {1, 2,....,N} in increasing order (each exactly once). Find the maximum length of its contiguous subsequence with an even sum.

This is the code that I came up with,

```
#include <stdio.h>
int Nsum(int n);

int main(void) {
    int t, n;
    scanf("%d", &t);
    while(t--)
    {
        scanf("%d", &n);
        int z = Nsum(n);
        printf("%d\n", z);
     // printf("%d\n", sum);
    }
    
    return 0;
}

int Nsum(int n) {
    int count = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + i;
        count++;
    }
    if (sum % 2 == 0)
    {
        return count;
    }
    else (Nsum(n - 1));
}
```

Comment: What are the failing symptoms?

Comment: `Nsum` does not return a value on all control paths. Change it so it always executes a `return` statement.

Comment: This does not seem like a very useful exercise. Given a sequence 1, 2, 3,… N, if the sum of the N integers is even, then the maximum length of a contiguous subsequence with an even sum in N. If it is odd, then the maximum length is N−1 (from the subsequence 2, 3,… N). Is the problem stated correctly?

Comment: I guess the code is "working" with the missing return, but fails for eg: N=5.

Comment: @jarmod: OP does not know what the failing symptoms are. They have only test cases that appear to work. The grading/judging software is reporting a failure to them without telling them the test case or its results.

Comment: @EricPostpischil do we know that? Autograders often emit some information such as a testcase name or something like "Your function returned 12 when processing [1,3,9] but the expected value is 13". If nothing else, the OP knows his test fails. How does he know it fails? What information did it yield?

Comment: I guess `else (Nsum(n - 1));` was meant to be `else return Nsum(n - 1);`.

Comment: Also, pay attention to input limits.  You didn't say how large `N` may be, but the problem description likely gives a limit.  That affects your choice of data types.  And if the input `N` can be especially long (20 or more digits, say) then it might require a different approach.

Comment: @John Bollinger
You mean like `return n<0 ? 0 : n%4==1 ? n-1 : n%4==2 ? n-2 : n;`? :)

Comment: @ikegami, I mean that if `N` can contain 20 or more decimal digits, then chances are poor that even `unsigned long long` can represent all allowed `N`s. In that case, an approach is required that does not depend on parsing (all of) `N` as a value of one of C's built-in types.  But yes, computing `N % 4` would probably factor into such an approach.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yes, you can view the problem here, https://www.codechef.com/LP1TO201/problems/MXEVNSUB it's one of the Code Chef's self learning from 1* to 2* Basic learning problem. Can you suggest how I can declare the largest value of N?Perhaps maybe putting a while (2<=N<=10^5)? I am sorry, I am just starting out with coding. And I changed Nsum so that return is always executed just like John Bollinger suggested- else return Nsum(n - 1) . But I am still wrong somewhere else. Thankyou so much for helping me out. Much appreciated.

Comment: Although I now understand that making a new function was not necessary, what could have been better is if I determined the sum of **N** numbers as **N*(N+1)/2** and checking if it is even (print **N**) or odd (print **N-1**). But still I want to understand why my program fails.

Comment: The program in the question fails because `else (Nsum(n-1));` does not return a value. You said in comments you modified the function to return a value, but we do not see that code. If it says `else return Nsum(n-1);`, then that is wrong because, if `sum % 2 == 0` is false, that does not mean the length of the maximum even-sum subsequence for `n` is the length of the maximum even-sum subsequence for `n-1`. In other words, you have not written `Nsum` to compute the correct answer.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Oh right. Now I get it, it's like if `n=6`, then the sum is `21`, and the sum of `n-1` is `15` which is also not an even sum. But shouldn't calling `Nsum` for `(n-1)` in the last line when `sum` is not even, make it pass the value `n=5` then again calling `Nsum` for `n=4`? I am trying to call a function within itself until `Nsum` becomes even. I intended to only end the function when sum becomes positive, and then use return to hand the value of `count` to the `main` function. Thankyou.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Can you post an answer, showing the correct Nsum function? And can you please show how to define how large n can be? I am really confused about it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider these cases:

| N | Sequence | Sum of elements | A maximum subsequence with even sum | Its length |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | { } | 0 | { 0 } | 0 |
| 1 | { 1 } | 1 | { } | 0 |
| 2 | { 1, 2 } | 3 | { 2 } | 1 |
| 3 | { 1, 2, 3 } | 6 | { 1, 2, 3 } | 3 |
| 4 | { 1, 2, 3, 4 | 10 | { 1, 2, 3, 4 | 4 |
| 5 | { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 } | 15 | { 2, 3, 4, 5 } | 4 |
| 6 | { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 } | 21 | { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 } | 5 |
| 7 | { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 } | 28 | { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 } | 7 |

We can easily see patterns here. One pattern is that when the sum is even, the whole sequence { 1,… N } is the maximum subsequence with an even sum, and, when the sum is odd, chopping off the 1 to make { 2,… N } gives a maximum subsequence with an even sum.

Another pattern is that whenever N is even, the parity (evenness/oddness) of the sum of { 1,… N } stays the same from the previous N, since adding an even number does not change it. Whenever N is odd, the parity changes. So, the pattern is:

| N’s parity | Sum’s parity |
| --- | --- |
| even | stay the same |
| odd | changes |
| even | say the same |
| odd | changes |

It takes two changes to bring parity back to what it was. Two changes occur every two odd numbers, so they occur every four steps. Therefore, the parity of the sum goes through a fully cycle as N goes through four values. So the remainder of N modulo four tells us where we are in the cycle:

| N % 4 | Parity of sum | Length of a maximum subsequence |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | even | N |
| 1 | odd | N−1 |
| 2 | odd | N−1 |
| 3 | even | N |

Therefore, `Nsum` may be implemented:

```
int Nsum(int N)
{
    switch (N % 4)
    {
        case 0: return N;
        case 1: return N-1;
        case 2: return N-1;
        case 3: return N;
    }
}
```

(Note that negative N are not handled.)